# Human editable snippet store in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, templates, code-snippets

I am looking for a easier way to manage my eclipse code snippets. I know and have used Eclipse's template and snippets features. But as far as I have found, they can only be exported and imported as XML files.

Since I use many versions of eclipse and I keep migrating between machines managing the snippets is a hassle. I am looking for a [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) like method to manage these snippets/templates. Is there one?

I also looked at [snip2code](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/snip2code), but it didn't appeal to me because I sometime work offline. Also, I want to have much greater control over the snippets using version control.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well! I couldn't find anything that matched the set of requirements I had. So, I've ended up creating [my own](https://github.com/ZeroProbability/snipulti).